# Empty container before .appendTo() is fired using jquery

Tags: jquery, appendto

I have a container `#boxes` that I need to empty and add content to using `.imagesLoaded()` and then applying masonry. The content by default contains masonry items which I'm removing and then adding new ones contained within the response. The problem with my code is that it's emptying the content after the append I believe. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('div.profile-archive').click(function(){
        $("#boxes").empty();
        $this = $(this);
        var postType = $this.attr("rel");
        data = {
          action: 'fetch_profile_archive',
              postType : postType
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            var $response = $(response);
            $response.imagesLoaded(function() {
              $("#boxes").masonry('reload');
            }).appendTo("#boxes");
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the `imagesloaded` function. You currently append the result from `imagesloaded` to `boxes`, my guess is you have add the response to `boxes` first and then run `imagesLoaded` on `boxes`.

```
$("#boxes")
  .append($response)
  .hide() // If you don't want to show the content until loaded
  .imagesLoaded(function() {
    $("#boxes")
      .show() // If you want to show the content after it's loaded
      .masonry('reload');
  });
```

Comment: When I do this the content appears and then disappears.

Comment: Ok figured it out. Inside the `imagesLoaded` we just need to apply `.show().masonry('reload')` and it works fine. If you agree update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I edited both your original code and mine with `.masonry('reload')` so that they match.